# Resizing and splitting large tif image

Tags: python, reshape, tiff

I have imported a tif image in the form of a numpy array with shape (6400, 6400, 4) and would like to divide it in 25 smaller images of shape (256, 256, 4) and save them automatically as a tif file in a particular folder. (Loading with PIL or TIFFFILE gave issues because it is a satellite image which had an unknown fifth channel), hence the numpy array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

dummy data:

```
big_array = np.arange(6400) / 6400 * (np.arange(6400) / 6400)[:,np.newaxis]
big_array = (big_array * 256).astype(int)
big_array = np.stack([big_array]*4, axis=2)

big_array.shape
```

> ```
> (6400, 6400, 4)
> ```

split them:

```
split_arrays = [
    np.split(array, 25, axis=0) 
    for array in np.split(big_array, 25, axis=1)
]

split_arrays[-1][-1].shape
```

> ```
> (256, 256, 4)
> ```

PS. a 25 x 25 split results in 625 images, not 25